# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: state.coronaNews.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to update data in mongoDB. The data in the console.log() is correct. When I press the update button, I get endless pending and the error in the title of my post. But when I refresh the site, the update is fulfilled. All other crud operations in redux works without any issues. The updating of articles with image working too and I do it the same way, only that I didn't use FormData() in this onSubmit.

Here is my react-frontend:

```
const CoronaNewsEdit = () => {
  const {coronaNews, isLoading, isError, message} = useSelector((state)=>state.coronaNews);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {id} = useParams();

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(isError){
      window.alert(message);
    }
      dispatch(getCoronaNews(id))

  }, [isError, dispatch, id, message]);

  const [formdata, setFormdata] = useState({
    text:""
  })
  const {text} = formdata;
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(coronaNews){
      setFormdata({
        text: coronaNews.text
      });
    }
  }, [coronaNews]);

  const onSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const coronaData = {
      text,
    }
    const updateData = {id:id, coronaData: coronaData}
      console.log(coronaData); //correct Data
    dispatch(updateCoronaNews(updateData));
  }
```

My input:

```
            <FormGroup>
              <Label htmlFor='text'>News</Label>
              <Input type="text" name="text" id="text" defaultValue={text} onChange={(e)=>setFormdata({...formdata, text: e.target.value})}/>
            </FormGroup>
            <Button onClick={onSubmit}>Update</Button>
```

My redux-slice:

```
export const updateCoronaNews = createAsyncThunk("coronaNews/update", async (updateData, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.accessToken;
        return await coronaNewsService.updateCoronaNews(updateData, token);
    } catch(error){
        const message = (error.response 
            && error.response.data 
            && error.response.data.message) 
            || error.message 
            || error.toString();
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})
export const coronaNewsSlice = createSlice({
    name:"coronaNews",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: (state)=>initialState
    }, extraReducers: (builder)=>{
        builder
        .addCase(createCoronaNews.pending, (state)=>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        })
        .addCase(createCoronaNews.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.coronaNews.push(action.payload);
        })
        .addCase(createCoronaNews.rejected, (state,action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.message = action.payload;
        })
        .addCase(updateCoronaNews.pending, (state)=>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        })
        .addCase(updateCoronaNews.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isSuccess = true;
            state.coronaNews.push(action.payload);
        })
        .addCase(updateCoronaNews.rejected, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isError = true;
            state.message = action.payload;
        })
```

My redux-service:

```
const updateCoronaNews = async (updateData, token)=>{
    const config = {
        headers:{
            token: `Bearer ${token}`,
             }
    }
    const response = await axios.put(API_URL + updateData.id, updateData.coronaData, config);
    return response.data;
}
```

My backend:

```
router.put("/:id", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const updatedCoronaNews = await CoronaNews.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            $set: req.body,
        }, {new:true});
        res.status(200).json(updatedCoronaNews);
    } catch(error){
        res.status(404)
        throw new Error("Not found");
    }
});
```

Comment: are you getting a successful response from the backend??

Comment: Yes, after changing from the edit component back to the main site, the update is fulfilled.

Comment: what do you mean about endless pending??

Comment: When I press my update button in my dashboard, it opens an update page. There I enter the data in the input field. Then I press update, the spinner turns and the redux devtools show "pending". That not stops. To stop it, I redirect to the dashboard and the entry is updated. So it works, but I have to stop this "pending" and don't know why the devtools not show "fulfilled", like in the other update components.